# jQuery list slider stops when li elements are not evenly divisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If someone has a better, more descriptive title for this question, let me know; I couldn't think of a good title to describe my problem.

Anyways, I have some jQuery code that allows me to rotate through list items by displaying 3 `li` elements at a time.

However, I run into a problem when the amount of `li` elements that I have isn't evenly divisible by 3.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var j = 1;
var inbetween = 7000; //milliseconds   
function page() {
  var jmax = $("#leader-slider li").length;
  var count = 3;

  var start = j;
  var end = j + count - 1;
  var complete = 0;
  console.log(j, start, end);

  var range = $('#leader-slider li:nth-child(n+'+ start + '):nth-child(-n+'+  end +')');
  range
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(inbetween)
    .fadeOut(400, 'swing', function() {
      if (j++ >= jmax) {
        j = 1;
      }

      if (++complete >= count) {
        page();  
      }
    });
};
page();
});
```

This works beautifully when I have 3,6,9,12,etc. `li` elements. But as soon as I have a number not divisible by 3, like 8, it will cycle through all of them but after it shows the last `li` elements it stops the rotation and no longer shows anymore.

Comment: It's because `complete` is never `>= count`.

Comment: @pherris Do you have a suggestion on how I could go about fixing that? I'm still new to jQuery and JavaScript. I found this code and altered it a bit to fit my needs but I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your `complete` is never greater-than or equal-to `count` if you don't find exactly three elements with your jQuery.

It looks to me like you are already detecting when you've incremented beyond the number of `li` elements here:

```
 if (j++ >= jmax) {
    j = 1;
  }
```

If this is working correctly, you could call your page method here:

```
 if (j++ >= jmax) {
    j = 1;
    page();
 } else if (++complete >= count) {
    page();  
 }
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was that simple. That makes since though. Thanks!